# How to run my Java+Glassfish+JavaDB webapp outside of Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, javadb

Each time I need to run my application I need to run it from Netbeans, because it automatically runs Glassfish server and JavaDB, but Netbeans consumes lots of memory and I would like to run my webapp (JSP files) outside of Netbeans, how can I do this?

Comment: Google is your friend http://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1.1/quick-start-guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up `asadmin.bat` file in your glass fish installation folder\bin.

When that loads type `start-domain your_domain_name`

You can then access glass fish server form the admin console.

Default is `http://your_server_name:4848`

Comment: where to find my server_name or domain?

Answer (score 0):

Start the glass fish server.Deploy the war file to this server and access your application in the browser.